# Using aspstate with .net 4.0 and .net 2.0

Tags: .net, sql, t-sql, session-state, aspstate

I have some legacy .net 2.0 websites sites set up on my dev machine. I have been been developing a 4.0 site which has been working fine. In both cases the same session db is used.

If I access a 2.0 site it stops the 4.0 site from working giving this error:

> Unable to use SQL Server because either ASP.NET version 2.0 Session
>   State is not installed on the SQL server, or ASP.NET does not have
>   permission to run the dbo.TempGetVersion stored procedure. If the
>   ASP.NET Session State schema has not been installed, please install
>   ASP.NET Session State SQL Server version 2.0 or above. If the schema
>   has been installed, please grant execute permission on the
>   dbo.TempGetVersion stored procedure to either the ASP.NET application
>   pool identity, or the Sql Server user specified in the
>   sqlConnectionString attribute.

After restarting the machine the 4.0 site works again until the 2.0 site is loaded. Resetting IIS doesnt reset the problem - the only way I've found so far is restarting the machine.

The 4.0 site is using its own app pool and the sites are using different Users to connect to the db (although part of the same group).

Can anyone describe what is going on?

Comment: Based on my [reading](https://sqlblog.org/2010/09/10/a-quick-workaround-to-a-misleading-aspstate-problem), perhaps you just need to create that stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering in case others have the same problem. These sites were running under the same site but as different applications, different app pools, different users. As soon as I created a completely new site everything worked. I still dont really understand what was going on but thats definitely a solution.